Jenkins doesn't define docker image in cleanup section
I have such cleanup script
    post {
        cleanup {
            echo 'Cleaning up workspace'
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'url to docker image'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            script {
                dir("${projectID}")
                        {
                            sh("skaffold --kubeconfig ../kubeconfig delete -p eks -f skaffold.yaml")
                        }
            }
            deleteDir()
            script {
                for (item in list) {
                    clearTmpImages item
                }
            }
        }
    }

but when I run this script via Jenkins, it raises error "WorkflowScript: 281: Missing required parameter: "image" @ line 281, column 17.
docker {"
all path, words are correct, this script works well when it runs within stage{}.
Can you help?
I tried to run without script

post section doesn't have an agent statement. See the docs. What you could do is to use the node step instead.
post {
    cleanup {
        node(...) {
....
        }
    }
}

node syntax is not as flexible as agent, so you will have to define your docker image in Jenkins settings and give it a label.
